# Basic Recurrence Problem in the Analysis of Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I am taking an algorithm course at Coursera. From this [webpage](http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/10analysis/) by a Princeton Professor, Example 1.5 (Analysis of quicksort) gives the following codes.

> public class Quick
>
> {
>
> private static int partition(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi)
>
> {
>
> int i = lo, j = hi+1;
>
> while (true)
>
> ```
> {
>
>    while (less(a[++i], a[lo])) if (i == hi) break;
>
>    while (less(a[lo], a[--j])) if (j == lo) break;
>
>    if (i >= j) break;
>
>    exch(a, i, j);
>
> }
>
> exch(a, lo, j);
>
> return j;
> ```
>
> }
>
> private static void sort(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi)
>
> {
>
> ```
> if (hi <= lo) return;
>
> int j = partition(a, lo, hi);
>
> sort(a, lo, j-1);
>
> sort(a, j+1, hi);
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Define $C_N$ to be the number of compares to sort $N$ elements and analyze $C_N$. Then,

$C_N = N+1+\frac{2}{N}\sum\limits_{0\leq k\leq N-1} C_k$ is equivalent to

$NC_N=(N+1)N+2\sum\limits_{0\leq k\leq N-1} C_k$, which is equivalent to

$NC_N-(N-1)C_{N-1}=N(N+1)-(N-1)N+2C_{N-1}$.

**Questions**

I could not derive the third equation from the second. Indeed, if they are equivalent, then $2(C_o + C_1 + \dots +C_{N-1})=(N-1)(C_{N-1} -N)$. Is it true?

Also, the definition of $C_N$ looks a little fuzzy to me. In fact, I have googled the definition of "compares" for a while, but still could not understand it completely. Does $C_N$ define the number of comparisons we would make in order to compare $N$ elements? (Yes, this is my first algorithm course, and I have no java background.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second equation says that
$$2(C_0+C_1+\cdots+C_{N-1})=D_N\tag{1}$$
where we define
$$D_N=NC_N-N(N+1).$$
Replacing $N$ by $N-1$ in (*) gives
$$2(C_0+C_1+\cdots+C_{N-2})=D_{N-1}.\tag{2}$$
Subtracting (2) from (1) gives
$$2C_{N-1}=D_N-D_{N-1}.\tag{3}$$
That's your third equation.

From (3) one has
$$2(C_0+C_1+\cdots+C_{N-1})
=(D_1-D_0)+(D_2-D_1)+\cdots+(D_N-D_{N-1})=D_N-D_0.$$
But $D_0=0C_0-0=0$ so this recovers (1).

Comment: Thanks! Do you think my understanding of comparisons ($C_N$) is correct? It is the number of comparisons we need to make in order to compare $N$ elements?